# Add sub categories under categories in shop page

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I want to know if that possible to have :

1 section with main categories + 1 section with sub categories under

That mean : I click on 1 category > the sub-category section show all sub-categories of the category.

[image: explination]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Natively you can setup the native Category Tree Links module to always show the full
category tree in a single block (with expandable sub-categories of course) despite the context category you are visiting, like follows :

[image]

If you want to create two separate blocks, you'll need to heavily modify the module logic.

Comment: Yes, i need two separate blocks, so i will try by this way, thx :)